# Creating a dataframe by adding additional time

Tags: r, dataframe, interpolation

I have a long format dataframe (Main) where I want to add more days for I can interpolate a variable over these added days. The Main has firm name (type), days (day1), and a time-invariant variable (region), and a variable (value) that I need to interpolate.

```
#Main dataframe
Main<-data.frame(type=as.character( c("a","a","b","b"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE), day1=c(1,3,1,3), region=as.character( c("north","north", "south", "south"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE), Value=c(10, 30, 35, 50))
AA<-sapply(Main, is.factor)
Main[AA]<-lapply(Main[AA], as.character)
Main<- Main%>% arrange(type, day1)
#Dataframe that has additional days for interpolation
type<-unique(Main$type)
type<- rep(type, each=3)
day2<- rep(1:3,2)
Extra<-cbind(type, day2)
Extra<-data.frame(Extra)
```

This is the required dataframe for interpolation:

```
New<-data.frame(type=as.character( c("a","a","a","b","b","b"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE),day1=c(1,NA,3,1,NA,3), day2=c(1,2,3,1,2,3), region=as.character( c("north","north","north","south", "south", "south"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE), Value=c(10,NA, 30, 35,NA, 50))
```

How do I create the above mentioned datafame?
A side question: why do I need to remove factor classification even though I did not add them while forming the dataframe?

Comment: @Hack-R Kindly see line 2/3 of the first block of code.Some columns are factor class and I need character class.

Comment: Thanks. I was just confused by the use of the word "classification" instead of "class".

Answer (score 1):

Using `merge`:

```
merge(Extra, Main, by.x = c("type", "day2"),
                   by.y = c("type", "day1"),
      all.x = T, all.y = T)
```

> ```
>   type day2 region Value
> 1    a    1  north    10
> 2    a    2   <NA>    NA
> 3    a    3  north    30
> 4    b    1  south    35
> 5    b    2   <NA>    NA
> 6    b    3  south    50
> ```

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.type, 
              b.day1,
              a.day2,
              b.region,
              b.Value
      from Extra a left join Main b on 
      a.type = b.type and a.day2 = b.day1")
```

> ```
>   type day1 day2 region Value
> 1    a    1    1  north    10
> 2    a   NA    2   <NA>    NA
> 3    a    3    3  north    30
> 4    b    1    1  south    35
> 5    b   NA    2   <NA>    NA
> 6    b    3    3  south    50
> ```

The reason that you need `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` is that R will by default interpret character vectors in the `data.frame` statement as factors. That's just how the language is defined.

Note that the use of `a` and `b` are just aliases for the dataframe names. The statement above is the same as the one below:

```
sqldf("select one.type, 
              two.day1,
              one.day2,
              two.region,
              two.Value
      from Extra one left join Main two on 
      one.type = two.type and one.day2 = two.day1")
```

Please read this to clear up any confusion: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp but note that in the W3 Schools example they use *as* for table name aliasing which is not required by this version of SQL.

Comment: Thanks. However, I may need a general solution as "a" and "b" were just for illustration, I have more than 200 firm names.

Comment: @runjumpfly What does it matter how many firm names you have? Are you confusing the values of `type` with the arbitrary aliases of the data frames in the SQL statement?

Comment: :( I have no knowledge of sqldf

Comment: @runjumpfly It's just SQL. You can read more by typing `?sqldf`.  This is scalable to any number of values of `type` or any field. You could have 1 million firm names and the code wouldn't change.

Comment: Please see I have added some details.

Comment: @runjumpfly What I provided you is the result you requested. If you mean filling in the region then you forgot to include the necessary logic to change certain rows to north or south when they are logically NA as a result of the join. If you're just changing the values based on the position in the dataset then you'd use normal R indexing to recode all values above the cut off as north and all below as south.

Comment: Please see my last edit. Please do the needful I mentioned and I will surely accept your answer. Thank you

Comment: @runjumpfly I saw your last edit but it didn't supply the ***logic*** to fill in the NA region. Without the logic there are an infinite number of rules that you could use to replace the NA region with `north` or `south`. Please re-read my last comment. If you're just changing the values based on the position in the dataset then you'd use normal R indexing to recode all values above the cut off as north and all below as south. If you're using some other rule you need to specify that logic.

Comment: the region column is time-invariant so it will repeat values for type elements. But Value is Variable over time so I will interpolate NAs there.

Comment: This is required DF that I asked when I first posted the question (even before any edit was made): New<-data.frame(type=as.character( c("a","a","a","b","b","b"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE),day1=c(1,NA,3,1,NA,3), day2=c(1,2,3,1,2,3), region=as.character( c("north","north","north","south", "south", "south"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE), Value=c(10,NA, 30, 35,NA, 50))